# How to make an item always appear last on list (Netsuite Advanced PDF)

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I am trying to make an item appear last on the list if it appears on an in the invoice (Advanced PDF,NetSuite).

I was thinking bout trying to sort by and adding some ZZZs to the item name, but thats because I dont really know much outside of basic HTML.

Any Help would be appreciated.
Below is the table code I am dealing with.

```
 <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity@label}</th>
    <th colspan="12">${item.item@label}</th>
    <th colspan="3">${item.options@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount@label}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</#if><tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${item.item}</span><br />${item.description}</td>
    <td colspan="3">${item.options}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
```

I need the to be able to choose a specific itemname to always show at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the assign tag to hold the values for your bottom item.

```
<#assign bottomItemName = 'Bottom Item Name'>
<#assign bottomItem = {}>

<#list record.item as item>
    <#if item_index==0>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity@label}</th>
            <th colspan="12">${item.item@label}</th>
            <th colspan="3">${item.options@label}</th>
            <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate@label}</th>
            <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount@label}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </#if>
    <#if item.item == bottomItemName>
        <#assign bottomItem = bottomItem + item>
    <#else>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
            <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${item.item}</span><br />${item.description}</td>
            <td colspan="3">${item.options}</td>
            <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
            <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount}</td>
        </tr>
    </#if>
</#list>

<#if bottomItem.item??>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${bottomItem.quantity}</td>
        <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${bottomItem.item}</span><br />${bottomItem.description}</td>
        <td colspan="3">${bottomItem.options}</td>
        <td align="right" colspan="4">${bottomItem.rate}</td>
        <td align="right" colspan="4">${bottomItem.amount}</td>
    </tr>
</#if>
```

Comment: Thank you Jala, this worked. I am new to coding, what language or resource should I be looking at to learn more about the manipulation of these list?

Comment: There is a topic on HTML and FreeMarker for Scriptable Templates in NetSuite's Help Center. The full documentation for FreeMarker is here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping 2x.

```
<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th align="center" colspan="3">${item.quantity@label}</th>
    <th colspan="12">${item.item@label}</th>
    <th colspan="3">${item.options@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate@label}</th>
    <th align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount@label}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</#if><#if ${item.item}!="Your Item"><tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${item.item}</span><br />${item.description}</td>
    <td colspan="3">${item.options}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
    <#list record.item as item><#if ${item.item}=="Your Item"><tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td colspan="12"><span class="itemname">${item.item}</span><br />${item.description}</td>
    <td colspan="3">${item.options}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
```

I haven't tested the if statement, so good luck

Comment: Thank you for this, I received a few errors with it, and did not investigate further because the other post here's code worked. Thanks Again,